# how to get CustomView Bitmap point that overlay on textureView in onImageAvailable method

Tags: android, android-camera2

i'm using `camera2` API.
i want to get `CustomView` `Bitmap` point that overlay on `textureView` in `onImageAvailable` method.

> it is fragment_camera.xml.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tzutalin.dlibtest.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

   </FrameLayout>
```

> its CameraFragment.java.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dlog.d("onViewCreated");
    textureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
    surfaceView = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.view);
    eyeOverlayView = new CustomView(this);
    surfaceView.addView(eyeOverlayView);
}
```

> its CustomView.java

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Dlog.d("onDraw");
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setAspectRatio(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mStartRightX, mStartRightY, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mStartLeftX, mStartLeftY, null);
}
```

> its onImageAvailable method.

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {

    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

    if (image == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mIsComputing) {
        image.close();
        return;
    }
    mIsComputing = true;

    final Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("image size (%d,%d)", image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

    if (mPreviewWdith != image.getWidth() || mPreviewHeight != image.getHeight()) {
        mPreviewWdith = image.getWidth();
        mPreviewHeight = image.getHeight();

        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Preview size (%d,%d)", mPreviewWdith, mPreviewHeight));
        mRGBBytes = new int[mPreviewWdith * mPreviewHeight];
        mRGBframeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPreviewWdith, mPreviewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    mEyeOverlayView = eyeOverlayView;

    // I want to compare mEyeOverlayView.StartRightX, mEyeOverlayView.StartRightY to Specific point in mRGBframeBitmap
    // I know Specific point in mRGBframeBitmap. But it doesn't match the scale.
    // it is CustomView Bitmap scale on AutoFitTextureView and mRGBframeBitmap scale in onImageAvailable
}
```

I want to compare `mEyeOverlayView.StartRightX`, `mEyeOverlayView.StartRightY` to specific point in `mRGBframeBitmap`.

I know the specific point in `mRGBframeBitmap. But it doesn't match the scale.

It is `CustomView` Bitmap scale on `AutoFitTextureView` and `mRGBframeBitmap` scale in `onImageAvailable`.